# @keyframes not working properly for background images

Tags: css, background, hero

https://stellar-selkie-0b4aa8.netlify.app/ For the above website I’m working on, the images in the hero are meant to change according to keyframes, but the problem is upon loading on some certain devices it’s crappy, and secondly, once I leave the window and head back again, the images are gone and the default background is there.

Literally like a solution or an alternative way of implementing the hero background changing as opposed to keyfranes

Comment: I wasn't able to recreate it, provide more detail, what exactly is wrong? Can you also provide video?

Comment: New url is kaks.netlify.app. The exact problem is that: when you visit the page, there is the hero page with 100vh. The background images changes and the tech behind it is using keyframes to change the background image from 1-100. The problem is that the images don’t render well. Once you leave the window and get back to it, the background image is gone and the background is now black.

Comment: How can I upload a video here

Comment: for me it seems to cycle through the images and work well, use Imgur to upload a video and OBS to record.

There's one thing that might help, for images that don't have to be very high quality use .webp instead of .png. .webp weights way less and puts less load on the renderer, you can convert it online (beware some converters have daily limits). I do not think this is the cause of the issue though but it's better anyway.

Comment: I converted all the images but logo on the website to webp and yet the bug persists. I did the conversion via command terminal cwepb